# Include Multiple Labels and change the value of the same in Iphone, Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I m trying to insert label in each row of the cell. Displaying integer.
and I m trying to increase the quantity if user click on button add or minus
I able to insert button in UITableView Cell as well the function to change the value.
But when I click on add button it changes value only for the last row and not on the specific row.

//MY code to insert label in each cell

```
txtQty = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(233,7,20,20)];

txtQty.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[nos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

txtQty.tag = count;

txtQty.textColor =[UIColor whiteColor];

txtQty.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[cell.contentView addSubview:txtQty];


//Button Creation

UIButton *button2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180,5,30,30)];

[button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(subAddSubQty:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button2 setTag:count];

[cell.contentView addSubview:button2];
```

now what happening is suppose there are 3 rows in table
and I click on the 1st row add button the value gets change in the last label i.e at 3rd row
and not of the 1st row
How to solve these??
please help
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put a label into a `UITableViewCell`? It has a textLabel property:

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"SomeText";
```

That being said, what you want to do is not very difficult. I would use `NSMutableArray` instance variable full of `int`s. You can initialize the array using a `for loop`

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < someValue; i++) {
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someInt]];
}
```

in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you use:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] stringValue];
```

And in your button methods you increase like so:

```
-(void)increase:(id)sender {
    int correctIndex = sender.tag
    int old = [[array objectAtIndex:correctIndex] intValue];
    [array replaceObjectAtIndex:correctIndex withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:old + 1]];
}
```

You can get the `correctIndex` using tags. When you initialize a button in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you can set a tag:

```
button.tag = [indexPath row];
```

Comment: I am trying to add label cause I m already adding text with the cell.textLabel.text.   cause its like shopping cart where u see the item name and infront of that the quantity to increase or decrease it.   if I try to add the quantity next to the name its dont looks in line or align so for that I m using text label so that it will show the quantity at exact given frame

Comment: but you can use the other stuff I said?

Comment: yes I am using it. I am using tag but what happening is when I click on add button it increments value only at the last label in the table. suppose if I have 3 rows in table if I click on 1st row add button then in the method to increase the quantity its checking for sender tag. but then when I write as label.text = label.text intvalue +1 its increasing value of only the last label in row because the name remains the same for each label